# Why did Ethan Russell do this in the movie "The Woman in the Window" (2021)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-woman-in-the-window

I have recently watched the movie "The Woman in the Window" (2021) with Amy Adams. I probably missed something, because I do not understand why the son, Ethan Russell (played by Fred Hechinger), killed Jane Russell 1 (a.k.a Katie, played by Julianne Moore). What was his motive?

Thank you for your explanation and help.

Comment: Ethan reveals to Anna that he murdered Katie and is a serial killer -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woman_in_the_Window_(2021_film)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It wasn’t all in her head. Anna Fox, the former therapist suffering from agoraphobia, who regularly drank too much alcohol with her medication, did in fact witness a murder in her neighbors’ house; but neither the victim nor the murderer was who she thought. The "shocking" twist that the Russells' teenage son Ethan was the murderer was likely only a surprise to Anna, as Ethan was super creepy and suspicious throughout the movie. And the victim was not Jane Russell, as Anna kept insisting, but Ethan’s biological mother Katie.

https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2567586/the-woman-in-the-window-ending